# play 2.1.1: Unable to rollback transaction with ebean orm

Tags: java, transactions, playframework-2.1, ebean, traceback

I have problem with understanding how to work with ebean transactions under play 2.1.1.

```
    Ebean.execute(txScope, new TxRunnable() {

        public void run() {

            Ebean.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("[**] : " + Ebean.currentTransaction());
            User user = Ebean.find(User.class, 22);
            user.setPassword("qweqwe125");
            Ebean.save(user);

            user = Ebean.find(User.class, 22);
            user.setPassword("qweqwe126");
            Ebean.rollbackTransaction();
            // or other case
            //Ebean.currentTransaction().rollback();
        }
```

But in this case I receive error: PersistenceException: The existing transaction still active?

Also I've try to make something like:

```
@Transactional(type=TxType.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = TxIsolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public static void transactional2() {
    User user = User.query.getById(22l);
    user.setPassword("qweqwe123");
    user.save();

    Ebean.endTransaction();
}
```

In this case I receive updated values. Also in last example I've try rollback in this way:
Ebean.currentTransaction().end();

But receive NullPointerException error.

Could some one point me to workable example with transactions? Or write some example in comments.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Eventually have found solution:

```
public static void transactional2() {
    com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.beginTransaction();

    User user = User.query.getById(22l);
    user.setPassword("qweqwe123");
    user.save();

    com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.rollbackTransaction();
    // OR: com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.commitTransaction();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually have found solution.
Works for me.

```
public static void transactional2() {
    com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.beginTransaction();

    User user = User.query.getById(22l);
    user.setPassword("qweqwe123");
    user.save();

    com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.rollbackTransaction();
    // OR: com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.commitTransaction();
}
```

Please add you comments if something wrong with this solution.

Ebean documentation example: http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introtrans_begin.html

Comment: As said Rob, you shouldn't use the `begin`, `rollback`, `commit` directly. The problem you're pointing is a bug of Ebean : https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/pull/44. Try to upgrade your version of Play

Comment: You mean upgrade with Play 2.2.2, the last one from 1-st of March ?

Comment: A) If you use beginTransaction() ... then you SHOULD have a try finally block with endTransaction() in the finally.

Comment: B) You can use beginTransaction(), rollbackTransaction() etc OR @Transactional but not both together (as was the case in the original code example).

Answer (score 1):

In short you shouldn't use Ebean.beginTransaction(); Ebean.rollbackTransaction(); or Ebean.commitTransaction(); .... with either @Transactional or Ebean.execute(txScope, new TxRunnable().

So the enhancement of the @Transactional method handles the commit/rollback for you and similarly the Ebean.execute(txScope, new TxRunnable() handles the commit/rollback for you.

If you want to fail a transaction in say Ebean.execute(txScope, ... then throw an exception.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I've try to throw exception inside @Transactional controller action. Unfortunately all sql updates call was committed. Could you please point me to working example for play 2.1.1. Thank you for you comment.

Comment: This is not working. I am using `EbeanServer.execute(TxScope, TxRunnable);` and it does not rollback on trown exceptions.

Comment: David, put an example (e.g. failing test) of your issue somewhere. You could base it off https://github.com/ebean-orm-examples/example-minimal  ...