# Play 2.2.2 @Transactional of eBean does not rollback transaction in Exception thrown

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

It seems that when using Play Framework 2.2.2 with eBean ORM the @play.db.ebean.Transactional
does not rollback transaction when an Exception is thrown.

**Does someone of you know something about the issue and how it could be solved ?**

I saw that eBean has a BUG about that issue in their avaje-ebeanorm-agent 3.2.2. : https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/pull/44 which is fixed in version avaje-ebeanorm 3.2.3 
Also play 2.2.2 seems use avaje-ebeanorm-agent 3.2.2 and when I change it to higher version in 
Built.scala (3.2.5) some crashes with the used JPA annotations appeared (like orphanRemoval is not recognised)

P.S. There is similar discussion with Play 2.1.1 , [play 2.1.1: Unable to rollback transaction with ebean orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076055/play-2-1-1-unable-to-rollback-transaction-with-ebean-orm), but no clear resolving of the issue with using @Transactional in Action is found.

Answer (score 7):

I experienced similar problems, however I have only tested with play version 2.3.7.:

I noticed that there are two different libs that contain the Transactional-annotation: `@com.avaje.ebean.annotation.Transactional` and `@play.db.ebean.Transactional`.

Apparently each of them only work in a certain type of classes and when used wrong, no rollback will be performed. This is what I found out by testing:

- `@com.avaje.ebean.annotation.Transactional`:
  only works for methods in classes that represent a model, i.e. they have the `@javax.persistence.Entity` annotation. However there seems to be a bug in ebean enhancement, which causes the classes to [always recompile although no changes were made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986780/play-2-3-7-sbt-multiproject-compiler-issue/28148371#28148371)
- [ebean's documentation](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introtrans_begin.html) gives two other ways of implementing transactions, e.g. you can use a try/finally block. In my tests this way has always worked well and a rollback was performed.
- `@play.db.ebean.Transactional`: only works for actions, i.e. the class is derived from `play.mvc.Controller`. I'm not sure whether this behaviour is intended or not, but the [documentation of play-framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaEbean) only talks about transactional **actions** and doesn't mention model-classes at all.