# Play 2.3.7 sbt multiproject compiler issue

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, multi-project

we're using Play framework 2.3.7 and have set up a multiproject with sbt (sbt version 0.13.5), which is consisting of four modules.
In the build.sbt file of the project root we define the modules:

```
lazy val common = (project in file("modules/common")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)

lazy val store = (project in file("modules/store")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb).dependsOn(common)

lazy val catalog = (project in file("modules/catalog")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb).dependsOn(common)

lazy val backend = (project in file("modules/backend")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb).dependsOn(common)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb).aggregate(common, store, catalog, backend).dependsOn(common, store, catalog, backend)
```

If we're trying to run our application with

```
activator run
```

it compiles the app without an error. After the first request on the mainpage, it starts compiling the whole project again... up to four times.
This takes a long time, but after that everything works fine.

So what's the reason, the project is compiled that often? Anyone else stumbled upon this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue in my project after update to play 2.3.7 with ebean persistence-layer.

I noticed that **some classes always get recompiled** allthough no change was made to them. This only happened to `@Entity`-classes that used the annotation `@com.avaje.ebean.annotation.Transactional`.

Unfortunatly using the annotation `@play.db.ebean.Transactional` instead doesn't work, it won't execute the database commands within a single transaction. Not sure, wether there is either [still a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795548/play-2-2-2-transactional-of-ebean-does-not-rollback-transaction-in-exception-th) in it or this does *only* work for controller-classes but not for `@Entity`-classes.

However what fixed the issue for me, was using a `try/finally` block for creating a transaction as described in the [ebean-documentation](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introtrans_begin.html).

Do you happen to use ebean as persistence layer?

Does removing the `@transactional`-annnotation fix your problem?